# Liferay - Portlet only? WOA?

Tags: ajax, rest, liferay, portal, liferay-aui

All,

When lookin at Liferay, it is clear that using Portlets is one of the strong points of Liferay. When looking at a different approach, you quickly see the term 'WOA (Web Oriented Architecture', which basically boils down to SOA (over HTTP) using REST instead of SOAP.

If I understand it correctly, this is perfectly possible using AlloyUI (Liferay-AUI), the Javascript framework used by Liferay, using Ajax calls. I also see succesfull attemps using Angular.js in portlets.
However, when looking at the wiki page of Enterprise Portal Vendors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_enterprise_portal_vendors) , WOA is not listed as interfacing option for Liferay.

This probably means that my definitions of WOA are wrong, my understanding of the use of those Javascript frameworks are incomplete, something else, ....

Anyone can explain where I am missing something?

Thanks in advance!
Barry

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that AlloyUI or anyone else Javascript framework exclude the use of portlets??

What is a portlet in the final?

A piece of generated HTML, so you can generate it as you wish.

Comment: Hello Marco, Thanks for the comments. The thing is that I would like to avoid using Portlets, I have the string impression that it is a technology that is on its return, less and less used. I would like develop in a different way (using REST, for instance) and am not sure whether Liferay is a good fit. Sure you can generate and use it, but would that be 'natural', or are we bending the tool for a usage that should better be handled using a different tool?

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. However if you do not want to use portlets Liferay its not your tool. Where would you put REST calls? The entire LR is deeply portlet based, i don't think is pratical (or even possible) develop a Liferay portal without portlet!